# NSDateFormatter read timezone from string

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I have NSDateFormatter with date format string: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"`which converts date strings to NSDate as expected but how do I get the timezone info for the date string?

First I thought that niling timezone property on NSDateFormatter before parsing and reading it back does the trick but turns out that just restores the timezone property to system one...

Comment: You cannot get it from the `NSDate` object as it doesn't hold it.  You are probably looking at parsing the string yourself.

Comment: To be clear, you wish to know what timezone the original string specified? What do you need this for?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the timezone originally specified by the string. I would like to use something that works with date format strings (not regex).

Comment: Since you know the format of the string, simply get the substring starting at index 20. There's no other way.